# Sorting data using array

Tags: json, angular, sorting, typescript, ng2-charts

This is my components.ts.
I want to write a fuction that sorts array by counts and i will use the sorted array datas in html to create a chart.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.scss'],
  templateUrl: './dashboard.html',
})
export class Dashboard {
  private data = [];
  constructor() {
    this.data = [{
      'maxTime': 30041,
      'minTime': 6453,
      'avgTime': 18949,
      'count': 4,
      'requestRouteTemplate': 'api/GetUserPostponesCountReport',
      'requestMethod': 'POST',
    },
  ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Just as an addition to the answers. There is this neat library called [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) which I do recommend. With lodash you could simly `data = _.sortBy(data, 'count');`

Answer (score 2):

```
this.data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.count - b.count;
});
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Or just an ES6 shortcut:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count );
```

Because in one line you dont need `{}` also dont need return and also allowed the arrow function.

Comment: or just an ES6 shortcut:
data.sort((a, b) => a.count - b.count );
Because in one line you dont need {}  also dont need return and also allowed the arrow function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` function

```
this.data.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.count - b.count;
});
```

For reference - [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

For tweaking- [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDtOoqHfGNtRm5aYsLhc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in your dashboard.html file where you want to show data order by count

Like this way:

```
<tr  *ngFor="#friend in friends| orderBy : ['count']"">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.count}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Just a thought - OP wants data to sorted in a function in JS as data is needed for chart and `orderBy` might not be available.